# x2go: Xresources not loaded for client sessions

Tags: x2go

x2goclient is used to access a remote server. Everything works out greatly, yet the X session does not load .Xresources file automatically as I'd expect.

I tried to add the following line in the `.xinitrc`:

```
[[ -f ~/.Xresources ]] && xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
```

Yet it does not load the file neither.

Can anyone shred some light on how x2go session initialization process?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I just faced the same issue. Looking at `/etc/x2go/Xsession` I figured out that x2go is looking for the users X resources in `$HOME/.Xresources-x2go`. So `ln -s $HOME/.Xresources $HOME/.Xresources-x2go` will do the trick, if you want the same X resources for your local and remote sessions.

Comment: Furthermore, looking at `/etc/x2go/Xsession`, there are similar changes for other startup scripts: `.xsession-x2go`, `.xsessionrc-x2go`, `.Xsession-x2go`, `.Xmodmap-x2go` and `.Xkbmap-x2go`,